# Debian Buster install - it doesn't see my SSD

Tags: debian, ssd

I downloaded the debian from this [address](https://www.debian.org/download). And I copied the files into a usb. I tried running it but it couldn't detect my wifi card.

I also downloaded the firmware from this [address](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/buster/10.10.0/). And I copied them into the firmware file in the usb. This time it worked. Detected my wifi card.

But this time it can't see my SSD. Only usb is showing. And when I try to continue I get an error like this:

```
The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI2(0,0,0) (sda) failed.
```

I searched a bit on the internet but I couldn't find any solution for debian.

Can you help me?

Comment: Is the SSD visible in other OS installers, or in BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: @Panki yes.....